# Unity, keep playing music on different scenes

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I've been looking around and no solution seems to work to me...

I want to play some background music in all the scenes without resetting the audio.

I've a prefab with an audio source and a scritp.

the script does:

```
    private void Awake()
    {
        GameObject[] objs = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("BGAudio");
        if (objs.Length > 1)
            Destroy(this.gameObject);

        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
        
    }
```

So I also tagged the prefab with `BGAudio` but when i change the scene it stops the music. If i add the prefab to both scenes it starts from 0..

I tried also doing a singleton but that doesn't work either.

I'm using unity 2019
I'm using an android build which i doesn't think it changes anything but just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that `DontDestroyOnLoad` only works for objects on the root. While my `Bgsound` was inside a `bg` empty object.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a brand new scene that only includes your BGAudio object. Load both your BGAudio scene and play scene as additive.

For example: create a BGSound scene. Then create an empty gameobject called BGSoundManager. Also create your BGSound object. Then add a BGSoundManager script to your BGSoundManager gameobject and edit it like that :

```
private IEnumerator Start()
{
    yield return SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("BGSound", LoadSceneMode.Additive);
    yield return SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("Level1", LoadSceneMode.Additive);
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```